# web2py doesn't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, web2py

I installed web2py as source and wanted to use DAL without the rest of the framework.

But DAL does not connect to mysql:

```
>>> DAL('mysql://user1:user1@localhost/test_rma')
...
RuntimeError: Failure to connect, tried 5 times:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Whereas MySQLdb can connect to the database with the same credentials:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='user1', passwd='user1', db='test_rma')
```

A [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891376/web2py-wont-connect-to-mssql) with MsSQL was solved by explicitly setting the driver object. I tried the same solution:

```
>>> from gluon.dal import MySQLAdapter
>>> print MySQLAdapter.driver
None
>>> driver = globals().get('MySQLdb',None)
>>> print MySQLAdapter.driver
None
```

But still the driver is None.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution of the problem. I had to write:

```
MySQLAdapter.driver = globals().get('MySQLdb',None)
```

instead of

```
driver = globals().get('MySQLdb',None)
```

I misread that line in the original question.